# Разработка игры. Рандомное определение координаты по определенному условию

Tags: java, разработка-игр

Делаю игру змейка:

[image: фото игры]

Есть проблема в определении рандомных координат яблока, которое не должно попадать на стены, которые находятся на границах поля.

Comment: `Как исправить?` - не класть яблоко на стену.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если ты карту заполняешь двойным for'ом, а координаты яблока выбираются рандомно(как я понял), то используй следующую формулу для определения x/y-координат:
**Координата по X** = **1 + (int)(Math.Random() * (Максимальная длина X - 1) )** 
**Координата по Y** = **1 + (int)(Math.Random() * (Максимальная длина Y - 1) )** 

P.S.Если у тебя есть препятствия на карте, то используй цикл while для определения координат и проверки свободности клетки, при успешной проверки - идет выход из цикла.